# counting number of occurrence in string

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the number of times "bob" has occurred in a given string. this is what I tried:

```
s = input("give me a string:")
count = 0
for i in s:
    if i=="b":
       for j in s:
           x=0
           if j!="b":
               x+=1
           else:
               break
       if s[x+1]=="o" and s[x+2]=="b":
           count+=1
 print(count)
```

if I give the string "bob", it gives back 2, and if I give something like "jbhxbobalih", it gives back 0. I don't know why this happens. any idea?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't do `s.count("bob")`?

Comment: You set `x` to zero each turn through your `for j` loop, so `x` is not the index of the `'b'` you have found. If you want to loop with an index, you could use `enumerate`; but `count("bob")` obviates the need for any of this.

Comment: Green Cloak Guy yes I supposed to do this with the things I currently have.

Comment: You inner loop is completely decoupled from your outer loop (`i` is not referenced at all in your `j` loop).  Instead of iterating `i` over the characters of the string, instead make it an index into the string.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest manual count would probably use indeces and slices. The main difference between this and the much simpler `s.count("bob")` is that it also counts overlapping occurrences:

```
# s = "aboboba" -> 2
count = 0
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if s[i:i+3] == "bob":
       count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking 3 consecutive characters, if they are 'bob', just add our counter up, and do nothing otherwise.

Your code should be like this:

```py
s = input("give me a string:")
count = 0
for i in range(0, len(s) - 3):
    if s[i] == 'b' and s[i + 1] == 'o' and s[i + 2] == 'b':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

100 % working this will work for all string.

```
import re
def check(string, sub_str):
count = 0
val = re.findall(sub_str, string)
for i in val:
    count+=1

print(count)
# driver code


string = "baadbobaaaabobsasddswqbobdwqdwqsbob"
sub_str = "bob"

check(string, sub_str)
```

This gives the correct output.